# How to correctly set the bold font in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

I have recently decided to switch on another font for vs code, and the problem is, that i can set up Regular font, but i can't somehow switch to bold, I use the paid version of MonoLisa Basic Font, in the editor it looks like this:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "MonoLisa",
```

What i need to change in the settings json, so i can use one of this fonts, that are installed on my pc "MonoLisa-BoldItalic.ttf", "MonoLisa-RegularItalic.ttf".

I have tried to set up the font like this:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "MonoLisa Bold",
```

**or**

```
"editor.fontFamily": "MonoLisa Italic",
```

But it does not change the situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to bold version of the font by setting the `editor.fontWeight`  to `bold`:

```
"editor.fontWeight": "bold"
```

**Update:**

For the italic one, you can use the `fontFamily` but with naming equal to the font file name:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "MonoLisa-BoldItalic"
```

Comment: it can't be used for instance for italic

Comment: @Vladyslav what about `"editor.fontFamily": "MonoLisa-BoldItalic",`

Comment: oh thanks bro it worked, i was trying this for one hour